# Changing text direction in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ with both English and Hebrew. As a result, I frequently have to change the direction of the text (ctrl+alt+'R'/'L'). However, when I do any of that, it reverses the whole document, including even the line numbers. Strangely so, if I minimize the window and open it again, it gets fixed.

Any reason for this peculiar bug? Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is seems to be a N++ bug in v6.5.

There are related bugs still open, see [#1721](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/1721/), [#3781](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/3781/) and I don't know if this is a coincidence, but a few hours ago the exact same bug that you found has just been reported, see: [#4550](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4550/)!

As a general comment, if your language is a right-to-left one (like Hebrew), I would suggest to try another editor in complement. Because at some point you will need to edit a bidirectional text, and Notepad++ is not good handling that (has *limited* support). Check this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Right-to-left_and_bidirectional_text) list of text editors supporting RTL & bidirectional (and notice N++'s entry).

Answer (score 0):

Old Notepad++ versions work **OK** with this function... 
Search for Notepad++ Pro.v6.3.3.rar that also include user.manual  guide not present in recently versions.