# Notepad++ Mirrored Right to Left Text

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ Version 6.5.5.

I am using both English and Hebrew, hence alternately need to switch back and forth from
Left-To-Right English text to Right-To-Left Hebrew text.

While pressing ALT+CTRL+R:

1. Page layout flips to the right side as expected.
2. However, all text appears mirrored.

In order to see text correctly I need to refresh my display in one of these methods:

1. Pressing F11 twice, OR
2. Pressing F12 twice, OR
3. Minimize then Maximize window.

While pressing ALT+CTR+L:

1. Page layout flips back to the left side as expected.
2. However, all text appears mirrored again.

This problem seems to appear just in recent versions as it didn't happen in the past.
Is there any solution for that?
If not I'd like to downgrade Notepad++ to the last version (BTW which one was it?) it worked correctly. So where can I find it now?

Answer (score 24):

## TEXT DIRECTION KEYS

Press CTRL+ALT+L --> Text Direction Left to Right

---

Press CTRL+ALT+R --> Text Direction Right to Left

---

Answer (score 5):

This is a [confirmed Notepad++ defect #4782](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4782/). As you can see, Notepad++ author (Don Ho) personally gave it priority **8** out of 9 what means it is considered high and it got **Accepted** status so it will be fixed relatively soon. If you wish to stay informed from first hand, you can **subscribe news** related to given defect.

Answer (score 2):

I know, late response... but I hope it will help someone.

As you can see at @miroxlav answer, this is a Notepad++ bug. Anyway, if you want to work with right-to-left language (like Hebrew), you can use the workaround I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19863958/3114639): minimize the window and open it again; it got fixed to me!